# Why is this PHP validation still setting the value

Tags: php, regex, validation, preg-match

I am trying to validate a form field (to be used for First Name) for letters and dashes only, but regardless of how I implement the code, the value of $player_name is still being set.

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
            if (empty($_POST["player_name"])) {
                $nameErr = "Name is required";
            } else {
                $player_name = test_input($_POST["player_name"]);
                // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
                if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z -]+$/",$player_name)) {
                    $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
                }
            }
        }

        function test_input($data) {
           $data = trim($data);
           $data = stripslashes($data);
           $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
           return $data;
        }
```

The form has been implemented using the following code:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> 
       Registration Date: <input type="text" name="date_captured" id="date_captured" value="<?php echo $current_date; ?>">
       <br><br>
       Name: <input type="text" name="player_name" id="player_name">
       <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
       <br><br>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
    </form>

    <?php
        echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
        echo $date_captured;
        echo $player_name;
        echo "<br>";
    ?>
```

Even though the "Only letter and white space allowed" error is set and displayed, the value of $player_name is still set.

Comment: The value is assigned earlier and then it is being validated.You should validate `test_input($_POST["player_name"])` instead.

Comment: @user2696851 please ark and up-vote the answer. it will help others.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it using the following:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$fieldTitle = "Player Name";
if (empty($_POST["player_name"])) {
    $player_nameErr = $fieldTitle . $requiredErrorText;
} else {
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z -]*$/",test_input($_POST["player_name"]))) {
        $player_nameErr = $nameValidationErrorText;
    } else {
        $player_name = test_input($_POST["player_name"]);
    }
}
```